# Animate this in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if this is basic. I can't seems to understand `$this`.

```
 <div class="product" id="product" onclick="show(this)"></div>

        function show(){

          $(this).animate({
                  width:('100%'),
                  marginTop:top+'px'
              }, 600);

    }
```

This will not animate because i use `$(this)` . How to read the argument `this` directly ?
**I don't want to use** the jquery `onclick` event, but this `html` one.

Comment: What's `top ` in `marginTop:top+'px'`?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the standard JavaScript method for attaching event handlers and instead use an old-fashioned, worst-practices method?

Comment: @HereticMonkey because "product" will be a dynamic div that has no ID.

Comment: And? It is not necessary for an element to have an ID to attach an event handler to it. `$('.product').on('click', show)`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes i just realized i can do this from one of the answers here. Sorry! i am very new to jquery. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lose the inline JavaScript and instead use:

```
$('#product').click(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    width: ('100%'),
    marginTop: top + 'px'
  }, 600);
})
```

Comment: i can't, as i said. i have many "products" and they don't have an ID, and created dynamically. So they all call this single function

Comment: @hkrlys So then use a different selector. `this` would still apply to the clicked element

Comment: not sure i get your last comment. So what would be the answer ?

Comment: For example, `$('.product').click(function() {` would apply the click handler to all elements with the class of product

Comment: ooh ok ! thats what i need. So maybe edit your answer and i will accept. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this is the parameter being passed into the function:

```
    function show(myElement){

      $(myElement).animate({
              width:('100%'),
              marginTop:top+'px'
          }, 600);

}
```